# BS4 error 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'. Cannot parse html data

Tags: python-2.7, beautifulsoup

BS4 error 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'. Cannot parse html data.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

session = requests.session()

def get_sizes_in_stock():
    global session
    endpoint = 'https://www.jimmyjazz.com/mens/footwear/nike-air-max-270/AH8050-100?color=White'
    response = session.get(endpoint)

    soup = bs(response.text,'html.parser')

    div = soup.find('div',{'class':'box_wrapper'})
    all_sizes = div.find_all('a')

    sizes_in_stock = []
    for size in all_sizes:
        if 'piunavailable' not in size['class']:
            size_id = size['id']
            sizes_in_stock.append(size_id.split('_')[1])

    return sizes_in_stock

print (get_sizes_in_stock())
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Haku.jpg)

Comment: 1) don't post photos of the code. Post the actual code so users can replicate the error. 2) the reason you get that error is because it's not returning any object. The most likely reason is the site is dynamic and data generated with javascript

Comment: thirdly, I just ran your code and works fine for me. output: `['11438227', '11395436', '11438228', '11395437', '11438229', '11395438', '11438230', '11438231', '11395439']` Is the site possibly being blocked on your end?

Comment: Thank you @chitown88 for the feedback and response. Don't know if the site was being blocked at my end for some reason it just keeps throwing the same error. I am using python 2.7. Finally, i had to use selenium to load the source page and then used bs4 to parse the data.

Comment: hmmm/ i was using 3.6, so maybe thats it. but selenium is the way to go when all else fails

Comment: You could also try adding the `headers` parameter in. See below, and let me know if that worked.

Comment: @chitown88 you are a genious. I used the header and now the code works without selenium which makes it much faster. Thank you very much for your help. Looks like the website now thinks I am not a headless browser anymore.

Comment: it works with the previous code. However, when I try the same thing with another website it throws same error as before i.e. nonetype object type has no attribute

Comment: What’s the other website url? I’ll give it a look

Comment: Other website url is  "https://www.sneakers76.com/en/nike/5111-nike-af1-type-ci0054-001-.html". All I want to do is get all numbers beginning with 791 from the html source code.

Answer (score 0):

try adding in the headers parameter:

change:

```
response = session.get(endpoint)
```

to:

```
response = session.get(endpoint, headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.100 Safari/537.36'})
```

Answer (score 0):

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

session = requests.session()

def get_sizes_in_stock():
    global session
    endpoint = "https://www.sneakers76.com/en/nike/5111-nike-af1-type-ci0054-001-.html"
    response = session.get(endpoint, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.100 Mobile Safari/537.36'})

```
soup = bs(response.text,"html.parser")
var = soup.find("var",{"blockwishlist_viewwishlist":"View your wishlist"})
all_sizes = var.find_all("var combinations")

sizes_in_stock = []
for size in all_sizes:
    if "0" not in size["quantity"]:
        size_id = size["attributes"]
        sizes_in_stock.append(size_id)
return sizes_in_stock
```

print (get_sizes_in_stock())